# Calling function in c will cause the string value in struct turn into garbage value

Tags: c, string, function, struct

This code has a problem in the struct data members. When I call a function like `Evaluator()` function the token[0].value will corrupt or will turn into a garbage. I tried to allocate a memory for the value data member but still no luck. I also tried to allocate a memory for the struct itself but still it doesn't work. Can someone help me with this?

```
    struct tokens               
{
    char *value;
    char type = ' ';
};




void inputComponent(char input_string[size])                    
    printf("\n> ");                                             
    scanf("%[^\n]s", input_string);                                 
}

int processingComponent(char *input_string, int *result)
{
    int error_flag = 0;                             

     tokens token[size];


    error_flag = Parser(input_string, token);   

    if (error_flag == 0)                                
        error_flag = Evaluator(result, token);          
    return error_flag;
}

int Parser(char *input_string, struct tokens token[size])
{
    char valid_operators[size] = { "+-*/%" }; 
    char temp = ' ';                                        
    char number_string[size] = { NULL };                
    int counter = 0;                                
    int countStruct = 0;
    int tempCounter = 0;
    do
    {
        temp = input_string[counter];           
        if (isdigit(temp))                          
        {
            number_string[tempCounter] = temp;          
            tempCounter++;
        }
        else if (strpbrk(input_string, valid_operators))
        {
            if (temp == '%')                            
                return (-1);                            
            else if (number_string != NULL)         
            {
                char tempNum[size] = { NULL };

                strcpy(tempNum, number_string);

                token[countStruct].value = tempNum;
                token[countStruct].type = 'N';
                countStruct++;
                tempCounter = 0;
                for (int x = 0; number_string[x] != NULL; x++)
                    number_string[x] = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
            return (-2);
        counter++;
    } while (counter < strlen(input_string));

    return 0;
}

int Evaluator(int *result, struct tokens token[size])
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)    //value of token[0].value = ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ

        printf("%s", token[x].value);
    return 0;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])                    
{
    char input_string[size] = { NULL };                 
    int result = 0;                                     
    int error_flag = 0;                                 
    inputComponent(input_string);                   
    error_flag = processingComponent(input_string, &result); 
    _getch();
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not even compile. provide a [mcve], what you expect, what you input and where **exactly** you get the error. Use a debugger.

Comment: It does not come *close* to compiling.  There are some indications also that it is intended to be C++ code rather than C code (though it doesn't compile as C++, either).  C++ is a different language.

Comment: @ameyCU it is a string that holds the valid operators. It is use for the strpbrk().

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel, armeyCU's point, as I take it, is that the declaration is not valid (which it indeed isn't).  I don't think he's asking about your intended purpose for the variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  It looked weird , but to my surprise it complied . But really I think  that shouldn't  should be done .

Comment: The `value` field does not change. `temp_num` changes - because it is a local variable, it is destroyed when the function exits.

Comment: Can you not use a debugger to setup a write to memory breakpoint on the value being changed to garbage, then figure out who is doing the writing?  Compiler warnings should be respected as well...

Comment: @ameyCU, well, `gcc` rejects it with `error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`.  This is consistent with the standard, which indeed disallows such initializations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, when you pass an array of tokens to the Parser and Evaluator functions, you are passing the variables by value. The `token` array is not actually changed after calling `Parser()`:

`

```
int Parser(char *input_string, struct tokens myArray[size])
{
    //modifying myArray will not modify the array that was actually passed
    //to this function from the processingComponent() function.
}
```

`

First change your Parser and Evaluator functions like so:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100 //an arbitrary size

int Parser( char* input_string, struct token* tokenArray ) 
{
    //access each element as so:
    //tokenArray[0];
    //tokenArray[ ARRAY_SIZE - 1 ];

}

int Evaluator(int *result, struct token* tokenArray )
{
    for(int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++)
        printf("%s", tokenArray[x].value);
    return 0;
}
```

Then call the `Parser()` function as so:
EDIT: Since it is a good idea to allocate and free memory within the same function (so that you don't end up with spaghetti code), this would be a better solution:

```
int processingComponent(char *input_string, int *result)
{
    int error_flag = 0;                             

    token tokenArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

    //allocate memory here
    for( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ ) {
         tokenArray[i].value = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
    }

    error_flag = Parser(input_string, &tokenArray[0]);   

    if (error_flag == 0)                                
        error_flag = Evaluator(result, &tokenArray[0]);    

    //free memory here before the token array goes out of scope:
    for( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ ) {
         free( tokenArray[i].value );
         tokenArray[i].value = NULL;
    }

    return error_flag;
}
```

When you allocate memory for your token string, it needs to be dynamically allocated using malloc() and deleted using free().

Replace this:

```
strcpy(tempNum, number_string);
token[countStruct].value = tempNum;

//with:

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 255 //arbitrary

//Memory has already been allocated, so just copy the string into the token
strncpy( token[countStruct].value, number_string, MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 1 ); 
token[countStruct].value[MAX_STRING_LENGTH-1] = NULL;
```

Comment: so where should I put the `free()` function?

Comment: You want to `free` any memory that you allocate before it goes out of scope. So in this case you want to make sure it is freed before leaving the `processingComponent()` function because that is where you declared the token[] array. A good rule of thumb would be to allocate and free the memory within the same function: I'll edit my reply to show you what I mean...

Comment: No problem. I'd highly recommend reading up on memory allocation using malloc() and free(), and how to pass arrays to functions: handling strings and pointers can be tricky in C and introduce hard-to-find bugs later on down the road. There are some best-practices for things as well, such as using `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` to prevent buffer overflows (dangerous!) and also ensure you manually add null-terminators to strings. Just my opinion. Good luck!

Comment: Oh thank you. I learned a lot for this question and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be allocating any storage for token[].value.  You set it equal to tempNum, but that goes out of scope in the inner block in Parser().  I would say that anything this code does is undefined because you're accessing memory that was deallocated when Parser() returned.

Comment: So how can I allocate the token[].value? I tried allocating a memory in each index of token[] but still doesn't work.

Comment: Use malloc() for each token[].value you want to write to and then use something like strcpy() to copy the values into the memory you allocate.

Answer (score 0):

### Precautions with Structures

I have added a text file, which contains your running code with instructions.

one important thing you can not assign any thing directly into structure, because declaration of structure reserve no space.

Why did you do such a hectic job to achieve something like this..

input :12+3-1/7

output:12317

[Click this link to get your running c code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=72191293351AE1F2!128&authkey=!AISMIXvwjaSfmi8&ithint=file%2Ctxt)

Comment: To use pointer variable of structure you should have to do malloc each and every time with new variable.